# Changing a nested loop to print elements differently

Tags: java, loops, nested-loops

I have this nested loop.

```
for (Fencerss fencer1 : team1.getFencers()) {
    for (Fencerss fencer2 : team2.getFencers()) {
         PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(fencer1.getName() + " " + "(" + fencer1.getNation() + ")"));
         PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" "));
         PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" "));
         PdfPCell cell4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(fencer2.getName() + " " + "(" + fencer2.getNation() + ")"));
         table.addCell(cell1);
         table.addCell(cell2);
         table.addCell(cell3);
         table.addCell(cell4);
   }
}
```

Where each team has two fencers, there are 4 fencers in total. So there is Fencer1 and Fencer2 in the first loop and Fencer3 and Fencer4.

That means that table will be added to the document like this -->

```
Fencer1 " " " " Fencer3
Fencer1 " " " " Fencer4
Fencer2 " " " " Fencer3
Fencer2 " " " " Fencer4
```

What I am trying to do here is to make a change in the nested loop so the output be like this in the end:

```
Fencer1 " " " " Fencer3
Fencer1 " " " " Fencer4
Fencer2 " " " " Fencer4
Fencer2 " " " " Fencer3
```

In fencing, players have to connect the electric wire and things might take time, that's why it's best to make fencers either play consecutively or make it so there is time between the matches. Fencer4 playing match 2 and 3 and Fencer3 playing match 1 and 4 makes this very convenient.

Comment: How is the desired output "ordered"? I don't see an order here. Can you explain the logic here?

Comment: What is the desired output for each team having 3 fencers, or 4 fencers? What should happen when the number of fencers on each team is different?

Comment: My bad I didn't explain this enough. I am making a fencing tournament application, real fencers are going to be playing against each other every round. the loop should orderly print the document, so, the fencers know when they will play. For example here the nested (for loop) is looping with the first (for loop) that is Fencer1 and Fencer2. that means it will be printed like this (match1) Fencer1 vs Fencer3, (match2) Fencer1 vs Fencer4, then (match3) Fencer2 vs Fencer3 and (match4) Fencer2 vs Fencer4. But this doesn't make sense Fencer4 should be playing match 2 and 3. and I can't do it right

Comment: each team must have 2 fencers. It can be changed in the settings and I can get the exact number with a function I made: "variables.numberopairs". but usually the pair are made of just 2 fencers. There is a possibility that a team of 2 can encounter a team that is made of only one fencer, but I face no problem with that because of the way the loop functions

Comment: Why should Fencer4 play match 2 and 3? FYI, I don't know how fencing works.

Comment: Okay so in fencing, players have to connect the electric wire and things might take time, that's why it's best to make fencers either play consecutively or make it so there is time between the matches. Fencer4 playing match 2 and 3 and Fencer3 playing match 1 and 4 makes this very convenient